# How do I make Octopress use the system version of Ruby?

Tags: ruby, octopress

I am trying to setup Octopress on my Mac. The default version of Ruby on my Mac was 1.8.7 but I have upgraded it to 2.0.0.

If I do:

```
which ruby
```

it prints:

```
/Users/liqiushi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
```

After cloning my existed sources from github and 'cd'ing into that folder, I got the following error:

```
You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and it is
not compatible with other ruby managers, you can switch to
'.ruby-version' using 'rvm rvmrc to [.]ruby-version' or ignore this
warning with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore
/Users/liqiushi/Documents/photosynthesiis.github.com/.rvmrc', '.rvmrc'
will continue to be the default project file in RVM 1 and RVM 2, to
ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore
all.rvmrcs

ruby-1.9.3-p448 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448'
```

If I do:

```
ruby -v
```

in the Octopress folder it prints:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

And, if I do:

```
which ruby
```

It prints:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Can anyone tell how to make Octopress use the Ruby I just upgraded in my Mac instead of using 1.8.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Octopress is using your system ruby, `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]`.

You're using RVM, the `ruby-2.0.0-p247` is a ruby you've installed.  The repository has an `.rvmrc` file saying it wants `ruby-1.9.3-p448`.  Try installing it, or change what the `.rvmrc` wants.

edit:  The error message tells you what to do:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p448 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448'
```

Comment: could you tell me more and how to do it in detail, I am new to mac and ruby. thanks @Nick Veys

Answer (score 0):

RVM has a "default" Ruby that, immediately after installation, you should have set using:

```
rvm use 2.0.0 --default
```

See RVM's `rvm help use` command and "[Setting the default Ruby](http://rvm.io/rubies/default)" for more information. That covers the cases where you don't have a .rvmrc file in the directory.

For directories where it exists, you can remove the file:

```
rm ./.rvmrc
```

Or edit it to contain the information for the version you do want RVM to use when you `cd` into the directory.  See RVM's "[RVM Best Practices](http://rvm.io/rvm/best-practices)" for good tips on dealing with RVM in general and the tip of the discussion about [using .rvmrc files](http://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc). RVM's "rvmrc" capability is pretty nice. The previous link 'splains it nicely and details settings you can adjust to make your life a lot easier.

In that page you'd find:

> As of RVM 1.8.0, after a survey where greater than 80% of respondants wanted the feature on by default, automatic loading of project .rvmrc files is opt-out by default (therefore on). In order to disable this feature, set the following value in either /etc/rvmrc or ~/.rvmrc:

```
rvm_project_rvmrc=0
```